# Error ios 8.4 simulator en xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

Estoy tratando de descargar el simulador de `iOS 8.4` en `Xcode 7` y me devuelve este error:

> Could not download and install ios 8.4. Authorization is required to install the packages.

Antes de eso ingresé mi password de usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow quizas quiera echar un vistazo a esta pagina http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para realizar esta operación, ejecuta `Xcode` como `root` con el comando [`sudo`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) e instala dentro de esa sesión:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Una vez hayas instalados debes salir e iniciar normalmente.

Debes tener precaución si tienes proyectos abiertos cuando usas sudo para lanzar Xcode.